# What is the current state-of-the-art in Reinforcement Learning regarding data efficiency?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, algorithm-request, state-of-the-art, sample-efficiency

In other words, which existing reinforcement method learns with fewest episodes? [R-Max](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/brafman02a/brafman02a.pdf) comes to mind, but it's very old and I'd like to know if there is something better now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very interesting learning agent. They call it Neural-Episodic-Control. Here is the link for the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01988 . Their experiments show that NEC requires an order of magnitude fewer interactions with the environment than agents previously proposed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really one specific method which makes any RL agent have faster learning. Rather there is a long list of methods which have shown to increase the speed of learning and they can sometimes play nicely with each other.

Some examples:

1. [Options](http://www-anw.cs.umass.edu/~barto/courses/cs687/Sutton-Precup-Singh-AIJ99.pdf)
2. [True Online Methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.04087)
3. [Asynchronous Methods](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01783)

These are the most influential and promising methods I can think of but the list of techniques is not limited to these 3.